Rider - custom (vpn) nuget sources restores forever
I'm using Rider on MacOS and have external sources in my nuget sources. Those external sources are only accessible through VPN and credentials.
This causes a problem for me. Every time I open a solution when not connected to the VPN the SLN can't restore the packages, it's just trying "for ever":

The nuget packages can be found in the cache, but it still want's to check the "VPN sources".
Is there a way to set some kind of "abort time"? Or some kind of solution not being "disable the sources in the nuget source config", coz then I have to reenter credentials every time I want to use them.
Sometimes it works to just abort, but sometimes I can't run tests, build etc. until it's restored (even tho, as stated, the nugets are in the cache).

By default, NuGet has a 100 second timeout on individual HTTP requests, and makes 5 attempts. There's also exponential backoff between attempts, so factor in a 1, 2, 4, and 8 second delay between attempts. Check NuGet's docs on environment variables for how to change the values. So, the duration is capped, it should not freeze forever. If you're seeing delays longer than this 8.5 minutes, then something else could be going on.
